# Android Studio grab tables on http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=G13&region=SGP&culture=en_US

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, android-studio-3.0

I am using jsoup to grab this webpage:

http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=G13&region=SGP&culture=en_US

however, the return contain do not have tables on it.

I able to get the tables from the web using excel.

now I would like to create an app for this application. but it not work on Android studio. I think the web page has JavaScript in it.

tried below:

1. `doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();` ---> content of html code returned do not content tables.
2. `Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
   .ignoreContentType(true)
   .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
   .referrer("http://www.google.com")
   .timeout(12000)
   .followRedirects(true)
   .execute();
   doc = response.parse();`     ---> content of html code returned do not content tables.

please guide me on how to get the tables in the web page or what other solution should I use?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"?

Comment: sorry it is working, but the content of html code returned do not content tables.